# ListView: setvisibility() forces refreshing all the rows

Tags: java, android, listview, visibility, android-viewholder

I have a ListView with rows with different layouts. So I'm using the pattern of ViewHolder.

If the user clicks on a row, one sub-layout of the same row must be shown/hidden.

```
        viewHolder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
                Log.d(TAG, "Line in position " + position + " clicked");

                if (!checkBoxSendChoice[position]) {
                    checkBoxSendChoice[position] = true;
                    viewHolder.layout_choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    checkBoxSendChoice[position] = false;
                    viewHolder.layout_choice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

However I noticed that the entire ListView is refreshed (getView is called multiple times for all rows), because of setVisibility(). If I comment out the two setVisibility() instructions, the ListView isn't refreshed anymore.

Is it possible to optimize and avoid refreshing all the views in the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way of doing this. Instead of editing the view directly, you should have a `Boolean isVisible` inside the list item and change that, then notify the adapter that an item has changed. This will make the holder re-bind to the item. And inside the holder's bind function  you can set the view's visibility depends on the boolean. Here is a rough example (half pseudo code):

```
List<MyItem> items;

viewHolder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (int) v.getTag();
        Log.d(TAG, "Line in position " + position + " clicked");

        checkBoxSendChoice[position] != checkBoxSendChoice[position];
        items.get(position).isVisible = heckBoxSendChoice[position];

        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, 1);
    }
});

class MyItem {
    boolean isVisible = true;
}

class holder {
    View layout_choice;

    private void onBind(MyItem item) {
        if (item.isVisible) {
            layout_choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layout_choice.setVisibility(View. GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

By notifying the adapter with notifyItemRangeChanged, the adapter will know what items have been update and therefore will only refresh them.
If you want i'll be happy to edit my answer with a working tested example. Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, I couldn't understand why setting visibility of an element in one row in onClick() callback forces the redraw of all rows. It appears to me the most intuitive way to show/hide a part of the row.
However I couldn't understand your not immediate solution. Please, could you provide a full example? Your items list of boolean values is my checkBoxSendChoice[] array (that is really a boolean).